# Why is fetching data from MySQL via URL not working when “ ” is in the URL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, url

I have a table in MySQL database with `id`, `location`, `type`, `content` columns. If fetching a specific row via `id` in the URL, e.g. `domain.com/page.php?id=1` I can do this by:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM database_table WHERE id=" . $_GET["id"];
$rs = mysql_query($sql);    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

echo $row['location'] . $row['type'] . $row['content'] ;
```

However if I want to fetch it via the other rows in the URL, e.g. `domain.com/page.php?location=paris&type=housing`

I tried this replacing the first line of code above with this:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM database_table WHERE location=" . $_GET['location']
                                                         . "AND type=" 
                                                         . $_GET['type'] ;
```

the code does not work on this URL:

`domain.com/page.php?location=paris&type=housing`

but works with this URL (notice the " " between the row):

`domain.com/page.php?location="paris"&type="housing"`

My question: Is there anything I can do to make it such that I don't have to have the " " between rows in the URL in order for the query to work?

Comment: You just made yourself vulnerable to SQL injection. Please at least `var_dump()` your SQL queries and you'll be perfectly aware of what has gone wrong (hint: double quotes making syntax error).

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string on the value to protect yourself against SQL Injection a bit more. Even better would be to start using PDO.

Comment: Please could you share how to use PDO to achieve the same effect as the code above? Appreciate it alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM database_table WHERE location=" . $_GET['location'] . "AND type=" . $_GET['type'] ;
```

to

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM database_table WHERE location='" . $_GET['location'] . "' AND type='" . $_GET['type'] . "'";
```

Make sure you sanitize your $_GET data though.. you are vulnerable to mysql injection attacks. 
Mysql_query is also deprecated, use PDO.

You'll be able to call your script without quotes in the url:

> domain.com/page.php?location=paris&type=housing

Comment: You can also use MySqli.

Comment: Gudgip, thanks for this, it works well. Please could you share how to use PDO to achieve the same effect as the code above? Or point me in some direction.. I'm new at this. Thanks!

Comment: I will refer to this guide to get started with PDO: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html . You can get thesame effect as the code above, but safe and object oriented.